# Função equivalente a $() em um Objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

A minha ideia é o seguinte, como possuo muitas tarefas repetidas, criei um objeto JavaScript e acesso as funções referentes a ele por meio do `.`, por exemplo:

```
Objeto.funcao(params)
```

Porém preciso, de algo como o jQuery que utiliza tanto `$()` como `$.()`.

Como posso atribuir no objeto a seguir, uma função equivalente a `$()`? Tentei da seguinte maneira>

```
const $ = {
   $: function(text) { alert(text) }
   f1: function(text) { alert(text) }
   f2: function(text) { alert(text) }
}

$('texto padrao') // erro gerado pelo browser dizendo que precisa acessar como objeto

$.f1('texto f1') // retorna alert dizendo 'texto f1'
```

Comment: Defina $ como uma função (const $ = function...) , e depois "pendure" as funções f1, f2 na função ($.f1 = function...). Uma função também é um objeto em JS, então você pode colocar penduricalhos nele.

Comment: Obrigado exp, me ajudou muito